# Convert $(p\to q)\to(q\to r)$ to clausal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Convert $(p\to q)\to(q\to r)$ to clausal form

From the source I'm using, I know that the correct answer is

$\begin{align}
&\{¬p,¬q,r\}\\
&\{¬q,r\}\\
&\{¬r\}
\end{align}$

However, that's not the answer I'm getting. My procedure is:

$\begin{align}
&¬(¬p \mid q) \mid (¬q \mid r)\\
&(¬¬p \land ¬q) \mid (¬q \mid r)\\
&(p \land ¬q) \mid (¬q \mid r)\\
&(p \land ¬q) \mid ¬q \mid r\\
&(p \mid ¬q) \land (¬q \mid ¬q) \land (p \mid r) \land (¬q \mid r)\\
&\{p, ¬q\}\\
&\{¬q\}\\
&\{p,r\}\\
&\{¬q,r\}\\
\end{align}$

Clearly not the right answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From fourth line:

$[(p \land \lnot q) \lor \lnot q] \lor r$

$[(p \lor \lnot q) \land \lnot q] \lor r$

from which:

> > $\{ p,¬q,r \}, \{ ¬q,r \}$.

---

The original formula cannot be equivalent to the clauses:

> $\{ ¬p,¬q,r \}, \{ ¬q,r \}, \{ ¬r \}$.

For the valuation $v$ such that:

> $v(p)=v(q)=v(r)=$**t**

the original formula is evaluated to **t**; but $v(¬p \lor ¬q \lor r)=v(¬q \lor r)=$**t** and $v(¬r)=$**f**.

Thus:

> > $v((¬p \lor ¬q \lor r) \land (¬q \lor r) \land ¬r)=$**f**.

Comment: Thank you. I see how it works now. I guess the source I was working from also had the wrong answer, which led me to do it wrong as well.